# why this recursive code only prints one answer?

Tags: arrays, c

I made this backtracking recursive code.

this code shows every 4x4 array filled with 1, 2, 3, 4
but no duplication in every one row and line.

but this prints only one answers, what I expected is every answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// initializing array
void init_arr(int arr[][4])
{
    int x;
    int y;

    y = 0;
    while (y < 4)
    {
        x = 0;
        while (x < 4)
        {
            arr[y][x] = 0;
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
}

// check about promising correct
bool promising(int arr[][4], int x, int y)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 4)
    {
        if (arr[y][i] == arr[y][x] && i != x)
            return (0);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < 4)
    {
        if (arr[i][x] == arr[y][x] && i != y)
            return (0);
        i++;
    }
    return (1);
}

// recursive function
void fill_arr(int arr[][4], int x, int y)
{
    int n;

    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        init_arr(arr);

    if (y == 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return ;
    }
    else if (x == 4)
        fill_arr(arr, 0, y + 1);
    else
    {
        n = 1;
        while (n < 5)
        {
            arr[y][x] = n;
            if (promising(arr, x, y))
                fill_arr(arr, x + 1, y);
            n++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[4][4];
    fill_arr(arr, 0, 0);
    return (0);
}
```

when I put printf in if(promising), this comes out
[image]

it looks like some variables are not initializing, but when I put init function to every other line, it getting messier.

Comment: Tangential to your problem: The code in `init_arr()` should use `for` loops — it is simpler to read `for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) { for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) arr[x][y] = 0; }` (when it is formatted properly). You can reverse the `x` and `y` if you prefer.

Comment: Its better to add images as text here, some people cannot access images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fill_arr() isn't cleaning up before it leaves.

Add this line before the final brace:

```
    arr[y][x] = 0;
```